# Microsoft Outlook 2019 Add-in Unknown Publisher

Tags: c#, certificate, ssl-certificate, outlook-addin, publisher

I'm developing a Outlook add-in for reporting email and use Advanced Installer to build the package.
I added a proper certificate key into Registry when building the EXE file but our client got certificate issue when opening the Outlook below:

[image: Publisher cannot be verified]

I could not reproduce this issue on my PC. I'm not sure what need to do to get rid of this popup.
Please support. Thanks.

Comment: What is that proper certificate? One that is meant for code signing? You did buy that certificate, right? Is the CA trusted on that client machine?

Answer (score 0):

this is my [certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTQqe.png) . We just meet this error on Microsoft outlook 2019.